# Android, AsyncTask inside AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have no idea how to solve problem, which I met while designing API for Android.
API must contain a method which will be able to get `JSON Object` from specific URL. So, I decide to put into the method `AsyncTask` to achieve that.
After execution method from this API I need populate a `ListView`, but I do not know how. As far as I know it is not possible to put `AsyncTask`( from method in my API) into other `AsyncTask`.
Any ideas, solutions, suggestions?

EDIT:
In the other words I want to create a method which will call restful services and get `JSON`. 
This method will be executed (from other package) to populate `ListView` with the result.

My `AsyncTask`:

```
protected String doInBackground(HashMap<String,Boolean>... args)
    {
        JSONArray readings=null;
        JSONObject json = getReadingsFromDB(args[0]);

        try
        {   
            int i;
            readings = json.getJSONArray(TAG_READINGS);

            for(i =0; i<readings.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject ob = readings.getJSONObject(i);
                ReadingH newReading = new ReadingH();
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String id;
                String date;
                String humidity;
                String temp;

                if(!ob.isNull(TAG_TEMPERATURE))
                {
                    temp = ob.getString(TAG_TEMPERATURE);
                    newReading.setValue(TAG_TEMPERATURE, temp);
                    map.put(TAG_TEMPERATURE, temp);
                }
                if(!ob.isNull(TAG_ID))
                {
                    id = ob.getString(TAG_ID);
                    newReading.setValue(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                }
                if(!ob.isNull(TAG_DATE))
                {
                    date = ob.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    newReading.setValue(TAG_DATE, date);
                }
                if(!ob.isNull(TAG_HUMIDITY))
                {
                    humidity= ob.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);
                    map.put(TAG_HUMIDITY, humidity);
                    newReading.setValue(TAG_HUMIDITY, humidity);
                }
                readingsListH.add(newReading);
                readingsList.add(map);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
    {
        //  pDialog.dismiss();
        a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        a,readingsList,
                        R.layout.reading_item,new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_DATE,TAG_TEMPERATURE},
                        new int[]{R.id.ReadingID,R.id.ReadingDate,R.id.ReadingTemperature});
                a.setListAdapter(adapter);      
            }
        });
    }
```

doInBackground will be in my new method, but code from onPostExecute will be there where new method will be executed.

Regards

Comment: asynctask is a reference itself, you implement it wherever and use that (start) it inside your desired location (method)

Comment: You need to read some documentation on `AsyncTask` and do some searches for similar problems, since there are dozens posted here with answers. No, you do not use a second *AsyncTask*. If you are looking to build a quick restful client without diving much into Android, you should use a library, such as [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery).

Comment: I have read similar problems, but there is small difference. Others can modify onPostExecute() method, where we can put code to manage ListView - eg. populate it, I do not. Method getAll() in which aSyncTask is is included on my API.
Can I use method get from aSyncTask to wait for result and then in RunOnUIThread use result to populate ListView?

Comment: Why can't you use `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Because calling restful services is defined and coded in one place(method in my API), but code from `onPostExecute` - populating `ListView` - is in another. API will be one package delivered to other developers who will use it to develop theirs application - they do not have access to modify my `AsyncTask` (`onPostExecute`). In this moment I define API(create method to manage restful services) and develop first testing application(populate `ListView`).

Comment: If your `AsyncTask` is in charge of downloading and parsing the JSON data, have you considered letting the users of your API inherit from your AsyncTask and override `onPostExecute()` ? Have you considered the option of letting the clients of the API provide a callback that your `onPostExecute()` calls when it's done (this callback would receive the data obtained from the json)?

Comment: @frozenkoi very good point! I do not think about it earlier. If I only want to retrieve JSON from Restful services how could I use this library: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. onSuccess method do not return anything..